# Compare Calculated Fields to Current Date

Tags: json, t-sql, sequelize.js

**Background:**

We are trying to identify if notifications are due to go out against records that have configurable schedules.  So, for instance, a record could have:

- NotificationStep: 'week(s)'
- NotificationCount: 3
- StartDate: 2018-11-17

This would signal that 3 weeks after Nov 17 -- or the last time one of these notifications went out -- we need to send out a new notification.

In SQL this would involve comparing today to subquery (and possibly a union) utilizing the MAX() method.

**Question:**

Is there a good way to use today's date as the value by which you're comparing your calculated values against?

Something like:

```
myModel.find({
  where:{
    new Date(): {$gt: Notifications.max('date', {where: ... }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `sequelize.where` and `sequelize.fn`

Here you go :

```
myModel.find({
  where:
    sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('now') , {$gt: Notifications.max('date', {where: ... } )
});
```

> Note : sequelize.fn('now') // <---- Give you current time from DB

Comment: I have other conditionals that need to go in the WHERE statement.  So, I would have to either nest my WHEREs ...`where: { deleted: false, where: sequelize.where(...)}`, or use an Operator above the WHERE, like `myModel.find({$and: [{where: {deleted: false}}, {where: sequelize.where(...)}]}).

Comment: Another option might be to use this API where clause in a sub-FIND. `myModel.find({where: {deleted: false}, include: [{model:myModel, where: sequelize.where(...) }] })`.  But that's going to get a bit messy for the statement I have in mind.